# Cambiar el value de un select si el option ya está seleccionado

Tags: javascript, jquery, bucles

Tengo un boton que hace un append de un row con un select y sus opciones. Les di a esos select una clase (".nuevaDescripcionProducto"). El select tiene un option (con el value: "Seleccionar un producto") y el resto de las opciones se añaden con una llamada a la tabla de la base de datos. Bien, lo que quiero es: Volver a poner el option "Seleecionar producto" si elijo un option que ya está seleccionado en otro select. Tal vez lo entiendan mejor con una foto:

[image: ejemplo]

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
$(".formularioVenta").on("change", "select.nuevaDescripcionProducto", function() {

var nombreProducto = $(this).val();

var productos = $(".nuevaDescripcionProducto");

for (var i = 0; i < productos.length; i++) {

    var x = $(productos[i]).val();

    if(nombreProducto == x) {

        $(nombreProducto).val();
    }
}

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es complicado tratar de desactivar opciones en otros *select* cuando se realizan cambios en alguno de ellos, es mucho más fácil si realizas la verificación cuando uno recibe el foco, recorriendo el resto para saber qué opciones están seleccionadas y desactivarlas en el actual:

```js
$(".formularioVenta").on("change", "select.nuevaDescripcionProducto", function() {
    // En esta función puedes realizar otras acciones
    // Como asignar nombre a otro campo
    // O ejecutar petición AJAX para obtener más información, etc.
});

// Verificar opciones disponibles cuando un select recibe el foco
$(".formularioVenta").on("focus", "select.nuevaDescripcionProducto", function() {
    // Habilitar todas las opciones del select actual (el que lanzó el evento)
    $(this).children().removeAttr('disabled');
    // Cargar todos los select por clase
    let selects = $(".nuevaDescripcionProducto");
    // Obtener índice de select actual
    let curSel = $(selects).index(this);
    
    // Recorrer todos los selects
    for(let i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        // No desactivar si se trata del select que lanzó el evento
        if(i == curSel) {
            continue;
        }
        // Obtener índice de opción seleccionada en otro select
        let index = $(selects)[i].selectedIndex;
        
        // Desactivar solo si se trata de una opción válida
        if(index > 0) {
            // Esta opción ya fue seleccionada previamente
            // Desactivar en select actual
            $(this).children().eq(index).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="formularioVenta">
  <select class="nuevaDescripcionProducto" name="producto[]">
      <option value="">-- Selecciona un producto --</option>
      <option value="1">Producto 1</option>
      <option value="2">Producto 2</option>
      <option value="3">Producto 3</option>
      <option value="4">Producto 4</option>
      <option value="5">Producto 5</option>
  </select><br>

  <select class="nuevaDescripcionProducto" name="producto[]">
      <option value="">-- Selecciona un producto --</option>
      <option value="1">Producto 1</option>
      <option value="2">Producto 2</option>
      <option value="3">Producto 3</option>
      <option value="4">Producto 4</option>
      <option value="5">Producto 5</option>
  </select><br>

  <select class="nuevaDescripcionProducto" name="producto[]">
      <option value="">-- Selecciona un producto --</option>
      <option value="1">Producto 1</option>
      <option value="2">Producto 2</option>
      <option value="3">Producto 3</option>
      <option value="4">Producto 4</option>
      <option value="5">Producto 5</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Hay cosas que se pueden simplificar, pero me hice un lío tratando de explicarlo y por eso dejé dos `if` dentro del ciclo.

Comment: Triby, muchas gracias por esta solución, aunque aún no entiendo mucho cómo funciona. Soy bastante novato, ¿algún recurso que me recomiendes para llegar a comprender esta solución que me has dado mejor? Gracias, otra vez.

Comment: @mdrr5545, todo el código tiene comentarios para que sepas qué hace cada sentencia, si tienes dudas sobre alguna, pregúntame.